# Overwrite constants in config file in php

Tags: php, config

I have an application that connects to an external data source and needs to store credentials to do this. Currently it works but I want to expand this to give a user to update their credentials or insert them on first use of the application.

My current code (which works fine):

```
class Constants{
    const user = "username";
    const pass = "password";
}
```

I'm not adverse to switching to `define("user","username");` structure if it's better/more manageable.

My question is, what's the best way to take a variable from a user interaction (i.e. `$_POST['user'] = "newuser"` and overwrite the old `const user`, or create if it's not already there.

Comment: if you don't want the constants to not be constants why not just use static properties?

Comment: I could use static properties, but my understanding is when the property is updated it only lasts as long as the object exists. When the user calls the username property next time it will be the original one?

Comment: Static properties are associated with the class, not a specific instance of it. It will last until script/program is restarted.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it helps the question then. If the username has changed, the script needs to hold the new value when it is run again. Is the only option editing the file using fopen, str_replace and fwrite?

Comment: in your code you would just use `Constants::$username = "myusername";` then it would be set to that and globally accessible for the life of the execution of the script

Comment: You literally cannot update a constant. At the very least (with `define()`) you will trigger a PHP Notice and the old value is retained. If you try to redeclare a class constant you will trigger a fatal error. Your use case demonstrably precludes using constants. You should consider persisting any updatable, user-specific data in a database.

Comment: I understand the issue now. You want to go through and install process or whatnot and configure the application. For this you would want to write a file containing the config values (xml/ini/json or whatever) and then in a configuration step in the bootstrapping of your application consume the config file and apply the values to the constant class.